# Update table row with data from another table

Tags: sql

I'm quite new to sql and i need your help to solve this problem. I have 2 tables. What I want is to update a row from one table with data from another one but only if the values are different where the id is the same.

Like this:

Table A

```
ID       DESC   
1        asd
2        aaa
3        asda
```

Table B

```
ID  DESC   
1   asd33
2   aaa22
3   asda
```

And what I want is this update DESC table B with data from DESC A only if the values are different

Table B

```
ID   DESC   
1    asd
2    aaa
3    asda
```

Comment: Isn't asda3 different than asda?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: yeah it was a typo its asda not asda 3

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE B
SET B.DESC = A.DESC
FROM TABLEB B
LEFT JOIN TABLEA A on A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: When you have questions about SQL, especially T-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server) I suggest that you always start with the Microsoft Developer Network. The `UPDATE` syntax and examples are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx).

Comment: thanks men ill try this, on your script what i want to update is table B when desc is diferent then A

Comment: tell me just one thing why do y do the left join

Comment: Ah yea, that's misleading.  It doesn't matter in this case.  You can join (inner join).  I'm working on a script that requires left joins and just typed that.  Either will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Update TableB
   Set TableB.desc = TableA.desc
   From TableB INNER JOIN TableA  ON TableB.ID = TableA.ID
   Where TableB.desc NOT IN
   (Select ISNULL(TableA.desc,'') From TableA)
```